# Найти количество слов,которые имеют три подряд буквы А "AAA"

Tags: c++

Дано предложение, слова в каком разделе пробелами (одним или несколькими). Определить количество слов, содержащих "ААА".Решить с помощью символьного массива не используя строки.

Вот мой код,но он работает не совсем так как надо,может у кого нибудь будет код попроще?
Буду очень благодарен.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

int n = 255, m = 500;

bool FirstPStr(char* strRez, char* str)
{
    if (strlen(strRez) > strlen(str))
    {
        return NULL;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str) - strlen(strRez); i++)
    {
        char *newStr = new char[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(strRez); j++)
        {
            newStr[j] = str[i + j];
        }

        if (strcmp(newStr, strRez) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        delete[] newStr;
    }

    return false;
}

int foo(char* searchStr, char* str)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool noEmpty = false;
    char temp[n];

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; j < n && i < m; j++, i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '\0' && noEmpty)
        {
            if(FirstPStr(searchStr, temp))
            {
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
        else if(str[i] == ' ' && noEmpty)
        {
            if(FirstPStr(searchStr, temp))
            {
                count++;
            }
            std::fill(temp, temp+255, '\0');
            j = -1;
            noEmpty = false;
        }
        else if(str[i] == '\0')
        {
            return count;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[j] = str[i];
            noEmpty = true;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char str[]{"He FAAAl AAA  KAAAK     KaaAK A BAAAllll      "};
    char searchStr[]{"AAA"};
    std::cout << foo(searchStr, str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке есть две функции, которые сократят Ваш код в разы. Это функции [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) и [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr). Вот решение Вашей задачи с их использованием:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
 
int main()
{
    char input[] = "He FAAAl AAA  KAAAK     KaaAK A BAAAllll      ";
    
    // Счётчик слов
    unsigned int counter = 0U;

    // Находим первое слово в строке
    char *token = strtok(input, " ");

    // Пока слова в строке есть
    while(token)
    {
        // Ищем подстроку AAA в текущем слове. Если нашли,
        // то выводим его и инкрементируем счётчик
        if (strstr(token, "AAA"))
        {
            std::cout << token << std::endl;
            counter++;
        }

        // Ищем следующее слово
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // Вывод на экран количество найденых слов
    std::cout << "Found " << counter << " words\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно вообще по-хардкорному в виде короткого кода, без использования каких либо функций или классов или хедеров, за исключением `<iostream>` + `std::cout` для вывода в консоль:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/53qonWz7E)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char str[]{"He FAAAl AAA  KAAAK     KaaAK A BAAAllll      "};
    int cnt = 0;
    bool counted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= int(sizeof(str)) - 4; ++i)
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            counted = false;
        else if (!counted && str[i] == 'A' &&
                str[i + 1] == 'A' && str[i + 2] == 'A') {
            counted = true;
            ++cnt;
        }
    std::cout << cnt;
}
```

Вывод:

```
4
```